# How to embed the html5 page in hexo?

Tags: javascript, html, hexo

The question is just like the title said. I want to know how to embed a html5 page
with a src folder contains the images and a js folder contains the javascrpts in hexo framework.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the tag in head of html file, the html file can sucessfully generated in hexo framework. While How do I post a page contain this page(by using mark-down link grammer)?:

```
layout: false
```